# Using temporary tables for update in stored procedure mysql

Tags: asp.net, mysql, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

Can any one depict a simple example for using temporary tables in stored procedure for updating two tables in mysql?

Answer (score 0):

Two kind of temporary tables available. One is session based and the other one is global temporary table.

Below is the simple example:

```
    Select A,b,c into #MyTemp From MyDbTable
```

In the above example, #myTemp is the temporary table that you are creating. MyDbTable is the one that exist in your database. You can create multiple temporary tables.

I would suggest reading the article from here: [Link](http://www.mstecharticles.com/2011/11/sql-2005-inserting-table-data.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
 --Create a temp table and insert all these counts in it
  Create Table #OperatorReportCount(Id int identity,Particulars varchar(100),NoOfArticles int)

  --Insert these values in table
  Insert Into #OperatorReportCount(Particulars,NoOfArticles) Values('Articles processed',@ProcessedArticleCount)
  Insert Into #OperatorReportCount(Particulars,NoOfArticles) Values('Articles approved',@ArticlesApproved)
  Insert Into #OperatorReportCount(Particulars,NoOfArticles) Values('Articles rejected',@ArticleRejectedCount)
  Insert Into #OperatorReportCount(Particulars,NoOfArticles) Values('Rejections recieved',@RejectionsRecievedCount)
  Insert Into #OperatorReportCount(Particulars,NoOfArticles) Values('Articles put on hold',@ArticlesOnHoldCount)   

  --Select the operator count table
  Select Particulars,NoOfArticles From #OperatorReportCount
```